# Can't open link like "intent://" in android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to open link like `"intent://qr.nspk.ru/url-something/#Intent;scheme=someScheme;package=com.example.android;end#Intent;scheme=someScheme;end"` from an android application.

If I write something like this:

```
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(androidUrl))
startActivity(i)
```

I get this error:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> dat=intent://qr.nspk.ru/url-something/#Intent;scheme=someScheme;package=com.example.android;end#Intent;scheme=someScheme;end

But If I go to this link from browser, it opens and it open an app that I need. Can you help me to understand why I can't open link from app and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The `intent:` scheme is used for the browser to encode an Android Intent. If you want to use this URL from an Android app, you need to create an `Intent` from the URL like this:

```
val i = Intent.parseUri(androidUrl, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)
startActivity(i)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I didn't find about setting scheme in intent by googling

Comment: Happy to be of some assistance.

Comment: Any idea what's causing this to not work on Android 10?

Comment: @mr5 are you calling `startActivity()` from a background process (`Service` or `BroadcastReceiver`)?

Comment: does anyone know how to do this in React Native?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee You'll have a better chance of getting a response if you post a new question. Asking questions in a comment on an answer isn't particularly effective. Good luck!